# Creating a 3D Globe in HERE Maps API for JavaScript Similar to harp.gl

Tags: here-maps

I'm working on a project where I need to create a 3D globe visualization. In the past, I used harp.gl and its sphereProjection feature for this purpose. I am now transitioning to using the HERE Maps API for JavaScript and am looking for similar functionality.

Is there an equivalent feature in the HERE Maps API for JavaScript that allows for creating a 3D globe from a 2D map using HERE, similar to what sphereProjection offers in harp.gl?